# when you tap label, it doesn't work in ios5

Tags: html, ios, css

when you tap label, input is activeted.
doesn't work on IOS5 (iphone)
[onclick=""] [cursor:pointer] doesn't work T_T
is there any other way???

```
<input type="text"  class="inpt_nm" id="prf_nm">
<label for="prf_nm" onclick = "" style="cursor:pointer">TEST</label>
```

Comment: i dont think label has on click

Comment: Add gesture to your label and perform your method.. Keep in mind to label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;.